# How to create mapbox map same as https://demos.mapbox.com/boundaries-explorer/?country=US&layer=pos4&worldview=US#3.5/41/-100 in react js

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, boundaries

I am seeking to replicate a Mapbox map similar to https://demos.mapbox.com/boundaries-explorer/?country=US&layer=pos4&worldview=US#3.5/41/-100 in a ReactJS application. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to find GeoJSON data for postal code boundaries in the USA. Could you please guide me on how to create a Mapbox map with the same features as demonstrated in the URL provided? Any assistance on obtaining or generating the required GeoJSON data for USA postal code boundaries would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Here are the US Zip Codes - convert to GeoJSON and upload to Mapbox Studio or convert to vector tiles and serve them yourself - https://www.census.gov/programs-surveys/geography/guidance/geo-areas/zctas.html